# \usepackage{epigraph} with pandoc conversion to docx

Tags: pandoc, epigraphs

I use pandoc very successfully to convert my thesis manuscript to docx, but it seems to choke on the `epigraph`-package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}

\epigraph{Das Recht hat kein Dasein f{\"u}r sich, sein Wesen vielmehr ist das Leben des Menschen selbst, von einer besonderen Seite angesehen.}{Friedrich Carl von Savigny}

\end{document}
```

And this for conversion:

```
pandoc -f latex -t docx test-epigraph-conversion-pandoc.tex -o test-epigraph-conversion-pandoc.doc
```

Can I make pandoc aware and able to process my epigraphs?

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE with the yaml and a dummy md with an example of how are you calling the epigraph package?

Comment: @lf_araujo thanks, I've added an MWE and cleaned up the conversion command. I haven't used yaml. Not sure what you mean with "dummy md", but nothing gets converted if I output markdown either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, it seems the /epigraph package is not recognized by pandoc, unfortunately. Perhaps a bug?

My experiments: First, let's try markdown as output with command `pandoc -f latex -t markdown test.tex -o test.md --verbose`. There is no error message and I end up with an empty file.

Now what happens if I make the text SmallCaps, instead of emphasis:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}

\textsc{Das Recht hat kein Dasein f{\"u}r sich, sein Wesen vielmehr ist das Leben des Menschen selbst, von einer besonderen Seite angesehen.}Friedrich Carl von Savigny

\end{document}
```

And convert it to md with the previous command?

```
<span style="font-variant:small-caps;">Das Recht hat kein Dasein f[ü]{}r
sich, sein Wesen vielmehr ist das Leben des Menschen selbst, von einer
besonderen Seite angesehen.</span>Friedrich Carl von Savigny
```

Converting it to docx, also generates a working doc with small caps. It seems /emphasis is not supported, I would notify the authors in github about the issue.

Sorry I couldn't be of much help.

Comment: I have added it as an issue here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3523

Comment: Good luck. I  myself am interested in this as I am writing my thesis now... Never thought of using epigraphs until now.